# XSLT template match depending on a variable value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm processing multiple xml files with a single xsl file, some files need to be processed differently even if they have the same structure. Since the number of files is large and the parts that need to be processed differently are just a few nodes, rest being the same, I want to keep a single xsl stylesheet. I'm setting a param externally which tells what type of file is being processed; with this information how do I do a `<template match.../>` on the same node differently for different files?

**EDIT:** I had something like this in mind, I know it's not possible to have a template match inside if,

```
  <xsl:param name="type" /> <!-- this is set externally -->
    <xsl:if test="$type = 'XYZ'">
        <xsl:template match="a/b">
         ....
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$type = 'MNO'">
        <xsl:template match="a/b">
         ....
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: @JohnLBevan I'm using saxon parser, I'm able to set a param value externally

Comment: @JohnLBevan That's just plain wrong. You can supply external parameters and open additional XML documents at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly write

```
<xsl:param name="type" />

<xsl:template match="a/b[$type = 'XYZ']">...</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a/b[$type = 'MNO']">...</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That works beautifully! thought that would work only if I had an attribute value test which I could 'AND' with; Thanks!